# Setting a variable to the highest value in Access Database ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

I want to set a variable to a value in an Access Database table from aspx.vb.  I want to return the highest "PalletNumber" to txbPalletNumber textbox.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim connString As String
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

    Try
        ' Set the connection string.
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
   Source=C:\Users\SF7\Desktop\Shore Fresh Logistics_be_be.accdb"

        ' Open the connection.
        conn.ConnectionString = connString
        conn.Open()

        'Set the command properties.
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PalletNumber, MAX(PalletNumber) FROM 
        tblPalletNumber"

        txbPalletNumber.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        conn.Close()
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error handling
    End Try
    txbPackday.Text = DateAndTime.Now


End Sub
```

Comment: Your SQL statement won't work, you need to group by `PalletNumber`

Comment: You're returning 2 columns in your query for starters. Probably need to only have "MAX(PalletNumber)" there

Comment: What abney said. There seems to be no need for PalletNumber here. I really hope this is for a useful purpose and not for working out the next ID to insert, instead of using auto-generated unique IDs. Also `Catch ex As Exception
        'Error handling
    End Try` I hope this is unfinished, because it's not handling errors, it's just squashing them and pretending they don't exist, and then you have no idea that anything went wrong, or what the cause of it was. Lastly, using Access for a website backend is generally not a scalable approach if you have more than a handful of users.

Comment: You don't need the group-by if you're only selecting the max, all you need is `SELECT MAX(PalletNumber) FROM tblPalletNumber`

Comment: @soohoonigan  thanks for this, but still can't get the txbPalletNumber to show that value. Is vb code okay surrounding the SQL statement?

Comment: @ADyson Just starting a new project, definitely not finished, but maybe youre on to something I don't know how to do. PalletNumber is not the unique ID, there can be multiples of the same PalletNumber, but I want the user to know what the highest/ next PalletNumber is by making txbPalletNumber show that value. Does that make sense?

Comment: @a-- So you think: SELECT MAX(PalletNumber) FROM tblPalletNumber GROUP BY PalletNumber

Comment: if you only have one field you don't need the group by. soohoonigan pointed that out above already. I suggest you take some basic SQL tutorials because this is fairly bog-standard stuff you should probably get your head around. The query is not the reason you can't display the value. Try the query directly in your database to verify it does what you need. If you remove your try/catch in the VB it'll halt on any other code-related errors. You may need to convert the output of executeScalar to a string before you can display it in a textbox, since it returns `object` by default

Comment: Just to clarify what is already explained above. Since your query as is, will not work, and also is NOT a Scalar as you are returning more than one value.  You need: "SELECT MAX(PalletNumber) FROM tblPalletNumber"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. Thanks for all the help.

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim connString As String
    Dim test As String

    ' Set the connection string.
    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=C:\Users\SF7\Desktop\Shore Fresh Logistics_be_be.accdb"

        ' Open the connection.
        conn.ConnectionString = connString
        conn.Open()

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        'Set the command properties.
        cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(PalletNumber) FROM tblPalletNumber"
    test = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    txbPalletNumber.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    conn.Close()
        GridView1.DataBind()

    txbPackday.Text = DateAndTime.Now


End Sub
```